# A where Clause in Combo with left join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, where-clause

I can't figure out how to change the code that the conditions inside the left join clause needs to be true.

```html
<?php
$wurm_run = mysql_query("SELECT s.killperweek FROM statistik as s WHERE (LEFT JOIN wurm_stats as w ON tag = '$tag' and month = '$monat' and setflag = 0)  ");
while ($wurm = mysql_fetch_array($wurm_run))
{
$newkill =  $wurm[0] +1;
echo $newkill;

mysql_query("update statistik set killperweek ='$newkill' ") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("update wurm_stats set setflag= 1 WHERE tag = '$tag' and month = '$monat' ") or die(mysql_error());

}
?>
```

EDIT' I know that the query "works" if I change `WHERE` with `ON` but then it's not the result I want

Comment: Does this query even run ?

Comment: You need to learn [How to write joins?](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: use mysqli extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.killperweek FROM statistik as s LEFT JOIN wurm_stats as w ON YOUR_ALIAS_can_be_s_or_w.tag = '$tag' WHERE YOUR_ALIAS_can_be_s_or_w.month = '$monat' and YOUR_ALIAS_can_be_s_or_w.setflag = 0
```

I hope $tag contains your table alias and foreign key.